# Does the modal logic K have a sole sufficient operator?

Tags: logic, binary-operations, modal-logic

Does the modal logic K have a binary operator which, when composed only with itself, can produce $\wedge$, $\neg$ and $\square$?

I suspect that it doesn't: it probably makes a significant difference that K has infinitely many modalities (and hence infinitely many possible operators). I have seen that the modal logics S4 and S5 have sole sufficient operators (see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093894004) and [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2271247)), but S4 and S5 have finitely many modalities.

I ask in part because a proof that K has *no* sole sufficient operator might help to answer one of my other questions (about a sole sufficient operator for the relation algebra), but I am also curious about the question for its own sake.