# Techniques for showing that sole sufficient operators of a given arity do not exist for a given algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra, modal-logic

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459435/does-the-modal-logic-k-have-a-sole-sufficient-operator) yesterday which is interesting. It asks whether a binary sole sufficient operator for the modal logic K exists. I tried to find an example of a sole sufficient operator for K for a little bit before taking a step back and realizing that I don't know any proof techniques for showing that sole sufficient operators (of a given arity) do not exist for a particular algebra.

**What are some techniques for showing that a sole sufficient operator of a given arity does not exist?**

---

So far, I have come up with a way to show that a unary sole sufficient operator does not exist for the $\square, \lnot$ fragment of S5. The result holds in a wider variety of modal logics than S5, but S5 is a good starting point.

Let the following equations axiomatize an S5-algebra. Let $\lozenge$ abbreviate $\lnot \square \lnot$.

1. $ \lnot \lnot a \approx a $
2. $ \square \square a \approx \square a $
3. $ \lozenge \square a \approx \square a $

I claim that any algebra satisfying (1) and (2) that has a sole sufficient operator satisfies $\square a \approx a$ too; i.e. has [modal collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_collapse). Modal collapse is not in the deductive closure of S5, so asserting the presence of a sole sufficient operator has caused us to lose some models of our equation theory.

For proof, let $u$ be a sole-sufficient operator.

For some natural numbers $k$ and $l$, suppose $\lnot a = u^k(a)$ and $\square a = u^l(a)$.

Consider the formula $u^{2kl}(a)$.

- It is equivalent to $\lnot^{(2l)}(a)$ and thus $a$.
- It is also equivalent to $\square^{(2k)}(a)$ and thus $\square a$.

Thus it holds that $\square a \approx a$.